# Share functions between EXTJS and Touch Apps that follows MVC pattern - Sencha Workspace

Tags: sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am creating an Web App and a Mobile App using Sencha 
while doing so I am following sencha's recommended MVC pattern to develop these apps

Sencha recommends to create Worksapce and then create extjs and touch applications one by one  inside the workspace to achieve code sharing between the apps.

from their documentation i understand that a piece of code thats shared between the two apps must go under the workspace directory

but i fail to understand how do you access this code from the respective Apps

presently i am creating the global functions inside a app and is available in that app only

```
Ext.define('MyApp.common.Util', {
statics: {
foo:function(){
      ...
    }
});
```

and to access the function i use

```
requires:['MyApp.common.Util'] 
...

MyApp.common.Util.foo();
```

As u can see i can access function thats defined only under an app (MyApp.*.*). can anyone provide me an example how to define a functions outside the app (within a workspace) and access them from various apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example app here: https://github.com/WebAppSolutionInc/sencha-cafe-townsend
They put the ExtJS and Sencha Touch app together with DeftJS https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS